# Spring Security - Autowired not working

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, security, oauth-2.0

This is a practice project I am working on, to learn Spring Security and OAuth2.

Link to the zip of the project - 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxsYBg5XwboXdkpUdkhXWUd1Vmc

As soon as I add the below class, my autowired service fails :(
It gives NullPointerException.

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class MethodSecurityConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {
    @Override
    protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
        return new OAuth2MethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
    }
}
```

And I get NullPointerException `userService` in below rest controller.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/user")
public class UserCtrl {

@Autowired
@Qualifier("userService")
UserService userService;

@PreAuthorize("#oauth2.hasScope('write')")
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST,consumes="application/json")
private @ResponseBody ResponseMessage registerUser(@RequestBody User user){
    user.setUser_id(-1);
    return userService.createUser(user);
}

@PreAuthorize("#oauth2.hasScope('none')")
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
private @ResponseBody ResponseMessage loginUser(){

    CustomUserDetails temp =  (CustomUserDetails) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    System.out.println(temp.getUsername() + " logged in");

    ResponseMessage message = userService.getUserByUsername(temp.getUsername());

    if(message.getCode() == ResponseMessage.CODE_NOT_FOUND){
        return message;
    }else{
        temp.setUser((User)message.getData());
    }

    return userService.loginUser(temp.getUser().getUsername(),temp.getUser().getPassword());
}

@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.PUT,consumes="application/json")
private @ResponseBody ResponseMessage updateUser(@RequestBody User user){
    return userService.updateUser(user);
}

@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.DELETE,consumes="application/json")
private @ResponseBody ResponseMessage deleteUser(@RequestBody User user){
    return userService.deleteUser(user.getUser_id());
}
}
```

Here's how I defined my service :

```
@Service("userService")
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

@Autowired
private UserDAO userDAO;

@Autowired
private RoleService roleService;

public UserServiceImpl() {
    System.out.println("service");
}

@Override
@Transactional
public ResponseMessage createUser(User user) {
    if (null == userDAO.getUserByUsername(user.getUsername())) {
        int id = userDAO.createUser(user);
        user.setUser_id(id);
        roleService.createRole(new Role(RoleType.ROLE_USER, user));

        return new ResponseMessage(ResponseMessage.CODE_CREATED, ResponseMessage.DESC_CREATED, user);
    } else {
        return new ResponseMessage(ResponseMessage.CODE_EXISTS, ResponseMessage.DESC_EXISTS, user);
    }
}
```

Mvc configuration :

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"com.rawal.sweetnote.*"})
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

@Override
public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.enable();
}
}
```

Spring security config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

@Autowired
@Qualifier("userService")
UserService userDetailsService;

@Override
@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
}   
}
```

Security initializer :

```
@Order(1)
public class SpringSecurityInitializer extends  AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer{

}
```

DispatcherServletInitializer

```
public class AppInit extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer{

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return new Class[]{MethodSecurityConfig.class,WebMvcConfig.class};
}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return new String[]{"/"};
}
}
```

Hibernate config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:app.properties" })
public class HibernateConfig {
/**
 * This field is automatically injected by the spring framework from app.properties
 */
@Autowired
private Environment environment;



/**
 * Creates a session factory
 * @return {@link SessionFactory}
 */
@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
    sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.rawal.sweetnote.entities" });
    sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
    return sessionFactory;
}


/**
 * Creates a datasource after setting various database properties
 * @return {@link DataSource}
 */
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("db.drivername"));
    dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("db.url"));
    dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("db.username"));
    dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("db.password"));
    return dataSource;
}


/**
 * Sets up the hibernate properties and returns an instance of it
 * @return {@link Properties}
 */
private Properties hibernateProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
    properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
    return properties;
}



/**
 * Creates a transaction manager using the sessionfactory injected by spring and returns an instance of it
 * @param {@link SessionFactory}
 * @return {@link HibernateTransactionManager}
 */
@Bean
@Autowired
public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory s) {
    HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
    txManager.setSessionFactory(s);
    return txManager;
}


/**
 * Creates a hibernate template instance from the injected session factory.
 * We use this to perform various db transactions.
 * @param {@link SessionFactory}
 * @return
 */
@Bean
@Autowired
public HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate = new HibernateTemplate();
    hibernateTemplate.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
    return hibernateTemplate;
}
}
```

OAuth2 Resource Config

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class OAuthResourceConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter{

private static final String RESOURCE_ID = "restservice";

@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
    .antMatchers("/register").permitAll()
    .and().formLogin().permitAll()
    .and().logout().permitAll()
    .and().csrf().disable();
}

@Override
public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
    resources.resourceId(RESOURCE_ID).stateless(false);
}
}
```

OAuth2 Server Config

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
@PropertySource("classpath:app.properties")
public class OAuthServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter{

@Autowired
private Environment env;


@Autowired
private UserService userDetailsService;

@Autowired
private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
    endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore()).tokenEnhancer(tokenEnhancer()).authenticationManager(authenticationManager).userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
    security.allowFormAuthenticationForClients();
}

@Override
public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
    clients.inMemory().withClient("client")
    .authorizedGrantTypes("password","refresh_token","implicit")
    .scopes("read","write","trust")
    .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(Integer.parseInt(env.getProperty("refresh_token_validity")))
    .accessTokenValiditySeconds(Integer.parseInt(env.getProperty("access_token_validity")));
}

@Bean
public TokenStore tokenStore() {
    InMemoryTokenStore store = new InMemoryTokenStore();
    store.setAuthenticationKeyGenerator(new UniqueAuthenticationKeyGenerator());
    return store;
}

@Bean
public TokenEnhancer tokenEnhancer() {
    return new CustomTokenEnhancer();
}
}
```

Stacktrace for the exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
com.rawal.sweetnote.controllers.UserCtrl.loginUser(UserCtrl.java:40)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:115)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:177)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:176)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:121)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:670)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**UPDATE 1**

Modified the user controller as below(added greet1() and greet2()).
Now the funny thing is, the UserService property isn't null for these new methods.
But it is still null for the other methods.

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
@RequestMapping("/greet")
public String greet() {
    System.out.println(service.sayHello());
    return "Hello";
}

@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
@RequestMapping("/greet2")
public String greet2() {
    System.out.println(service.sayHello());
    return "Hello";
}


@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST,consumes="application/json")
private @ResponseBody ResponseMessage registerUser(@RequestBody User user){
    user.setUser_id(-1);
    return service.createUser(user);
}

@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
@RequestMapping(path="/",method=RequestMethod.GET)
private @ResponseBody ResponseMessage loginUser(){

    CustomUserDetails temp =  (CustomUserDetails) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    System.out.println(temp.getUsername() + " logged in");


    service.sayHello();
    ResponseMessage message = service.getUserByUsername(temp.getUsername());

    if(message.getCode() == ResponseMessage.CODE_NOT_FOUND){
        return message;
    }else{
        temp.setUser((User)message.getData());
    }

    return service.loginUser(temp.getUser().getUsername(),temp.getUser().getPassword());
}
```

However, if I disable prePostEnabled, everything works fine. This feels really stupid! Help!!!!!

Comment: Can you post your Spring config where `UserService` is being declared?

Comment: I didn't declare the service bean in a config. I annotated the service. I hope I am not wrong here.

Comment: In this case, I would be expecting `@ComponentScan("com.package")` in `MethodSecurityConfig`. The strange thing is that you're saying everything works fine without `prePostEnabled`.

Comment: I have several other configs as well. '@ComponentScan("com.package")' is in another config file. You want me post that as well?

Comment: Can you post the rest of your RestController class?

Comment: updated the question with security config and the controller as well.

Comment: Is that all your config? Do you declare any `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` or `WebApplicationInitializer` like `AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer`?

Comment: No `BeanFactoryPostProcessor`. Yes I have declared `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer` and `AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer`. I have other configs as well, like hibernate,oauth server and resource configs.

Comment: Can you please post them here as well?

Comment: Remove `MethodSecurityConfig.class` from your `AppInit#getRootConfigClasses` and try again. It will be picked up by the scan config in `WebMvcConfig`.

Comment: Tried that, same result. Null pointer exception :(

Comment: What version of Spring Security are you using?

Comment: 4.1.3.RELEASE - spring security, 4.3.2.RELEASE - spring framework, 2.0.8.RELEASE - Spring Oauth.

Comment: Ok, I ran out of hypothesis. As a last resource, I would remove all dependencies of `UserServiceImpl` (`UserDAO`, `RoleService`, etc) and try it again after adding them one by one.

Comment: Hmmm i see.. Im sleeping for now, maybe I need a break.. I'll try your last resource and get back to you.. Though, i dont know why it works when i make `prePostEnabled=false`.

Comment: Add the stacktrace and not only a vague description of the stacktrace. Also read [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-requestmapping-proxying) on proxies and controllers and what to be aware of.

Comment: @Trein I tried your way, dint get it to work :(

Comment: @M.Deinum I'll make sure that I post complete stacktrace henceforth. I read about the proxies and controllers, didn't get how its related to this exception though. :(

Comment: I added this constructor to the userService:
 
`public UserServiceImpl() {
  System.out.println("service");
 }`
and "service" is printed on console when i run it on server through eclipse. That means, the bean gets constructed. Maybe, somewhere it is destroyed and becomes null.

Comment: Also which line is line 40? Currently it is more or less guessing... Instead of field level injection use constructor injection and assign it in the controller. What I think is happening (althoug I haven't seen it before) is that your dependency is injected onto/into the proxy instead of the actual object wrapped by the proxy. Using constructor injected should prevent that.

Comment: Try adding `proxyTargetClass=true` to the @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity` annotation. One thing I noticed is that your bean isn't an actual proxy (no interfaces, and the default for `proxyTargetClass=false`, however the configuration might trigger early creation of your controller, in turn making it not eligble for all postprocessors.

Comment: `proxyTargetClass=true` no success.

Added constructor injection dint work as well.

`private UserService userService;
 
 @Autowired
 public UserCtrl(UserService userService) {
  this.userService = userService;
 }`

Comment: @M.Deinum I have updated the question with the new thing I observed. The userService is not null for the `UserCtrl#greet2()` and `UserCtrl#greet()`. Please help me if you can. As I really want to learn Spring Security well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, this is really stupid of "ME".
I just noticed that all methods in my controller were private. :(
Making them public solved the problem.

HOWEVER!!!!! I STILL WONDER HOW IT WORKED WHEN THE `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)` was set to `false`.

Please comment if you get this.

Hope this helps someone as stupid as me. :/

Comment: If you disable processing, you disable the creation of a proxy, the issue only arises when you have a proxy.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your controllers to `public` not `private`
as an example

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST,consumes="application/json")
public ResponseMessage registerUser(@RequestBody User user){
   // your code here
}
```